# How to get relative path of all the files and folders, in a particular given folder using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, structure, directory, relative-path

A folder(a shared folder (not local folder)) is given and i have to find all the folders and files inside that particular folder and get a output.

A Parent folder(shared folder) is given and I have to find all the child folders and grand child folders and files inside that parent folder.

I need an output like:

```
Parent\Child1\grandchild1\File.txt
Parent\Child2\grandchild1\File.txt
Parent\File1.txt
```

etc...

I want it to iterate through all the levels and want the entire path.
I work on Windows and need to achieve this using a BATCH script.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "Z:\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Wscript.Echo objFolder.Path
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
Next
Wscript.Echo

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
Next
Wscript.Echo
ShowSubFolders Subfolder
Next
End Sub
```

this VB script gives me the details necessary.

Comment: so you want only relative paths?

Comment: `tree` commands works like this, however it produces different output.

Comment: yes. i want relative path of all the files in the given folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your batch file:

`dir /b /s`

But make sure that you have either placed this file in the `Parent` directory before calling/running the batch file or go to  the `Parent` folder (using [Change Directory - CD](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)) in the batch file before running `dir`.

```
CD C:\Users\X\Desktop\Parent\
dir /b /s
```

or

```
dir C:\Users\X\Desktop\Parent\ /b /s
```

Nevertheless, you can find more information about a command you want to run in CMD Prompt by just writing the name of the command followed by `/?`.

Example:

`C:\> dir /?`